# ViewState, FormView, and Controls

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-2.0, viewstate

How do you (in Visual Studio) compare the controls in the different templates in a formview so you can track down a ViewState error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting copies of every control in all three templates.  If I didn't use the control in that template I would simply put it in a PlaceHolder control with it's visability set to FALSE.  These unused controls have only the required attributes with nothing bound to them.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can use the ChangeMode method on an Asp:DetailsView control to set the mode and therefor which template is used on the client side.

I think you can do the same with a FormView.

You can either set the mode explicitly on the client side or set it as a result of actions on the server side.